# Static HTML Page

Tags: html, css, static

Hello guys thanks in advance.
Im trying for hours to make a static html page but its not working 
OK the page is this http://blog.plaisio.gr/ 
I want to have the Header and Footer separated and i cant make them work exactly the same.
I used SnappySnippet and everything i know but its not working can i have some guidance on how to do this cause i have no clue...
I want to make a html page with the same header and footer that look and work the same with the website.
For example the code i write down the black collor at the menu when i hover the mouse isnt appearing.. and it took me hours searching the html and css files to find each different div class and id to make it..

Here is what i managed untill now...

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.art-header{
    margin:0 auto;
    height:195px;
    background-position:0 0;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    position:relative;
    width:1190px;
    z-index:auto !important;
}
.row{
    display:block;
    width:1190px;
    margin:auto;
    border-bottom:1px solid #000;
    height:2px;
    position:absolute;
    top:212px;left:0px;
    }
    .art-header a{
        font-weight:bold;
        text-decoration:none;
        letter-spacing:3px;
        color:black;display:block;
        float:left;
        }
        .art-header a:hover{color:#A02C32;}
        .region.region-top1{
            width:1190px;
            margin:auto;
            border-bottom:none !important;
            display:block;
            }
            .header-logo{
                display:block;
                height:64px;
                width:431px;
                background-repeat:no-repeat;
                margin-bottom:-6px
                ;margin-top:19px;}
.menu-bar{
    display:block;
    height:46px;
    width:1190px;
    border-bottom:6px solid #000;}
    ul.header-menu a{background-color:white;border-left:1px solid black;padding-top:11px;font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;height:29px;display:block;font-family:Helvetica;line-height:normal;letter-spacing:0px;margin-top:6px;padding-left:17px;padding-right:16px;}
    ul.header-menu a:hover{background:url(Files/menu-bg.png) repeat-x;color:#fff;

    ul.header-menu{float:left;width:70%;padding:0;margin:0;list-style-type:none;position:relative;left:15px;}
    ul.header-menu li{position:relative;float:left;}
    ul.header-menu li .new-events{background:url(Files/new_events.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height:18px;
    position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:5px;width:47px;}
    ul.header-menu > li.active > a:hover{color:#FFF;background:url(Files/active-menu.png) repeat-x;}
    ul.header-menu li{display:inline;}ul.header-menu > li.active > a{color:#FFF;background:url(/sites/all/themes/MyPlaisioTheme/images/active-menu.png) repeat-x;padding-right:19px;height:55px;border:none;padding-left:18px;}





</style>
</head>

<body>
<header class="art-header clearfix">  <div class="region region-art-header">
    <div class="block block-block" id="block-block-6">

                <style type="text/css">
#new{ display:block; width:46px; height:26px; background:url(http://www.plaisio.gr/images/radio-new.png) no-repeat center; position:relative; top:-10px; margin-left:302px; }
ul.header-menu > li.active > a.active { color: #FFF; background: url(/sites/all/themes/plaisioAcademy/images/menu-bg.png) repeat-x;}
</style>
<div class="header-logo"><a href="http://www.plaisio.gr/" title="Plaisio.gr"> <img src="Files/plaisio-logo.png" width="222" height="48"></a></div><div class="menu-bar"><ul class="header-menu"><li><a href="http://www.plaisio.gr/" title=" Plaisio.gr">ΠΡΟΪΟΝΤΑ </a></li><li><a href="http://stores.plaisio.gr/" title=" Δείτε τα καταστήματα του Πλαισίου">ΚΑΤΑΣΤΗΜΑΤΑ</a></li><!-- <li class="active"><a href="http://blog.plaisio.gr" title=" Plaisio Blog">BLOG</a></li> --> <li><a href="http://www.plaisio.gr/promo/CampaignCMS.aspx?cid=46" title="EVENTS" style="border-right:1px solid #000;">EVENTS</a><div class="new-events"></div></li></ul><div class="contactinfos"><img src="Files/contact-phone.png"></div></div>
</div>

  </div>




</header>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This isn't a very good question. What exactly is the problem? What are you seeing, and what are you expecting to see? Your link looks fine to me...

Comment: "I want to have the Header and Footer separated" .. what does that mean?

Comment: `ul.header-menu a:hover` didn't close 0.0

Comment: I need to have the Header menu and the Footer without the middle content on 1 single page dont want to load files

Answer (score 0):

use the style property **position:fixed** to make it fixed where ever required or else use *headhesive.js* [sticky header](http://markgoodyear.com/labs/headhesive/)

Comment: I dont want to make it from scratch i want to take the header and footer from here http://blog.plaisio.gr/ and place them in an html empty file and make them work standalone without the Css files already used